# How to filter in nested array without eliminating array parent in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'm trying to filter array that the results of value {purchase} id contain in array of {products.transactions.purchase} id.
I want to filter by transaction which have same purchase id value.

the data:

```
var data = [
  {
    "purchase": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb",
    "products":
      [{
        "transactions":
          [{
            "purchase": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb",
            "price": "25"
          },
          {
            "purchase": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4",
            "price": "23"
          }],
        "_id": "5ace995914a759325776aab0",
        "product_name": "Milk",
      },
      {
        "transactions":
          [{
            "purchase": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb",
            "price": "20"
          },
          {
            "purchase": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4",
            "price": "15"
          }],
        "_id": "5ace995c14a759325776aab1",
        "product_name": "Ketchup",
      }]
  },
  {
    "purchase": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4",
    "products":
      [{
        "transactions":
          [{
            "purchase": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb",
            "price": "22"
          },
          {
            "purchase": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4",
            "price": "21"
          }],
        "_id": "5ace995914a759325776aab0",
        "nama_produk": "Milk",
      },
      {
        "transactions": 
        [{
          "purchase": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb",
          "price": "14"
        },
        {
          "purchase": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4",
          "price": "13"
        }],
        "_id": "5ace995c14a759325776aab1",
        "product_name": "Ketchup",
      }]
  }]
```

i have been tried but only show child array

```
function filter() {
  let result = []
  let filter = data.filter(a => {
    return a.products.filter(b => {
      return b.transactions.filter(c => {
        if (a.purchase == c.purchase) result.push(c)
      })
    })
  })
  return result
}
console.log(filter())

// output
> Array [Object 
{ purchase: "5ace99b014a759325776aabb", price: "25" }, Object
{ purchase: "5ace99b014a759325776aabb", price: "20" }, Object
{ purchase: "5ace99d714a759325776aac4", price: "21" }, Object
{ purchase: "5ace99d714a759325776aac4", price: "13" }]
```

how to the output of filtered array like below output:

```
[{
  "purchase": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb",
  "products":
    [{
      "transactions":
        [{
          "purchase": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb",
          "price": "25"
        }],
      "_id": "5ace995914a759325776aab0",
      "product_name": "Milk",
    },
    {
      "transactions":
        [{
          "purchase": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb",
          "price": "20"
        }],
      "_id": "5ace995c14a759325776aab1",
      "product_name": "Ketchup",
    }]
},
{
  "purchase": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4",
  "products":
    [{
      "transactions":
        [{
          "purchase": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4",
          "price": "21"
        }],
      "_id": "5ace995914a759325776aab0",
      "nama_produk": "Milk",
    },
    {
      "transactions":
        [{
          "purchase": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4",
          "price": "13"
        }],
      "_id": "5ace995c14a759325776aab1",
      "product_name": "Ketchup",
    }]
}]
```

Thank you.

Comment: You only want one transaction? On your expected output, you only removed the 2nd transaction.

Comment: no, but want to transaction which have same purchase id value.

Comment: which property is purchase id value? `purchase`  or `_id`?

Comment: yes, purchase, not _id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` and `filter`

```
let result = data.map(o=>{ //Use map to loop thru the array
    o = Object.assign({},o);   //Clone the object. So any changes will not affect the original array.
    o.products.map(p=>{   //Use map to loop thru the products
        p.transactions = p.transactions.filter(v=>v.purchase === o.purchase);  //Filter the transactions of the products
    });
    return o;
});
```

Here is a snippet:

```js
var data=[{purchase:"5ace99b014a759325776aabb",products:[{transactions:[{purchase:"5ace99b014a759325776aabb",price:"25"},{purchase:"5ace99d714a759325776aac4",price:"23"}],_id:"5ace995914a759325776aab0",product_name:"Milk"},{transactions:[{purchase:"5ace99b014a759325776aabb",price:"20"},{purchase:"5ace99d714a759325776aac4",price:"15"}],_id:"5ace995c14a759325776aab1",product_name:"Ketchup"}]},{purchase:"5ace99d714a759325776aac4",products:[{transactions:[{purchase:"5ace99b014a759325776aabb",price:"22"},{purchase:"5ace99d714a759325776aac4",price:"21"}],_id:"5ace995914a759325776aab0",nama_produk:"Milk"},{transactions:[{purchase:"5ace99b014a759325776aabb",price:"14"},{purchase:"5ace99d714a759325776aac4",price:"13"}],_id:"5ace995c14a759325776aab1",product_name:"Ketchup"}]}];

let result = data.map(o => {
  o = Object.assign({}, o);
  o.products.map(p => {
    p.transactions = p.transactions.filter(v => v.purchase === o.purchase);
  });
  return o;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `filter` is being used as a `forEach` here. I have rewritten the filter function to provide the correct output:

```
function filter() {
  return data.map(dataItem => ({
    ...dataItem,
    products: dataItem.products.map(product => ({
      ...product,
      transactions: product.transactions.filter(
        transaction => transaction.purchase === dataItem.purchase
      )
    }))
  }));
}
```

The implementation in the question only pushed the child items to a result array.

In Javascript, `Array.prorotype.filter` is generally used to produce an Array that conditionally includes or exclude items based on the truthiness of the callback, as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).